# Delete Files Older than a Certain Number of Days on Windows 10 usin .Bat

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am new at this, but I am trying to make a .BAT file that can delete all files in a folder that is older then X days. I am able to do this using the Command Line, but when i use it inn a .BAT file it does't do anything.

My example:

```
@echo off
ForFiles /p “C:\Users\Username\Pictures\2018-03” /s /d -1 /c “cmd /c del @file”
end
```

If I use the line: `ForFiles /p “C:\Users\Username\Pictures\2018-03” /s /d -1 /c “cmd /c del @file”` in cmd it will delete all files older then 1day.

Comment: You have typographic quotation marks `“` and `”`, which are not understood by `cmd`; you have to use the normal ones `"` in your code! And `end` is not a valid `cmd` command, by the way...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl) that solved it.

Changing the quotation marks from `“` to `"` and removing the end fixed it. The BAT file now only has this line: `ForFiles /p "C:\Users\Username\Pictures\2018-03" /s /d -1 /c "cmd /c del @file"` and it now works